# Laravel Controllers __construct Issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller, laravel-5.4

So I am having a few dramas with my `controllers`. They seem to operate properly, however they don't seem to use `__construct()` at all in any of the `controllers`.. I'm trying to use this to update our `users table` to show last activity.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\UserHelper;
use App\Helpers\ForumHelper;
use App\Helpers\ShopHelper;
use Auth;
use Image;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Hash;
use File;

class AdminController extends BaseController
{

public function __construct() {
  if ($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]) {
    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
  }

  if(Auth::check()) {
    $time = strtotime("now");
    DB::table('users')->where('userid', Auth::user()->userid)->update(['lastactivity' => $time]);
  }

}
```

Any idea what I can do to check and try and get it working again?

I'm running `Laravel` Framework `5.4.28`

A project I did similar on was running `Laravel` Framework version `5.2.45` and worked fine when I was doing that so I'm confused why this is happening on a newer version.

Any ideas how I can otherwise go about implementing the `DB` Update when loading stuff from my `controllers`?

Comment: `Auth::check()` will not work in the constructor anymore. The constructor is called before the session is started. What you are doing should be solved using middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an activity tracker then add a web route middleware:

```
class ActivityTrackerMiddleware {
      public function handle($request,$next) {
            if ($request->user()) {
                $request->user()->lastactivity = Carbon::now();
                $request->user()->save();
            }
            return $next($request);
      }
}
```

Add this in your web middleware:

```
 'web' => [ ...
         StartSession::class,
         ActivityTrackerMiddleware::class,
         ...
  ];
```

You can also limit it to the admin controller if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, @apokryfos . I'll give that a go now!